# set notation: confusion about meaning of S and S'. Isn't S' the complement of S?

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

**TLDR: What is line 4 saying?**

In the context of Argumentation theory, an argument from a set of formulae $A$ is a pair $\langle S, x\rangle$, $S$ is the suport, $x$ the argument such that:

\begin{align}
 & S \subseteq A\\
 & S \not\vdash \bot \\ 
 & S \vdash x \\
 & no\; S'  \subset S \; such \; that \; S' \vdash x \\ 
\end{align}

Line 2: no value of $S$ leads to  $\bot$, and $\bot$ is literally FALSE. Meaning, S is never False.

line 4: this is where the confusion arises. I though $S'$ meant complement of $S$, but how can a set's complement be a proper subset of itself. What is $S'$ in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S'$ is just a different variable name. You could replace it with $T$. The aim of the statement is to convey that no proper subset of $S$ satisfies $x$.

Comment: Great! Thanks.

I have seen it used to mean complement, and I think rarely the way you said, as just another set.